# What is the advantage of RLC low pass filter over two RC conneced in series?

Tags: analog, filter, signal

I guess two RC in series should be a second order low pass filter. Because the transfer function will have s^2. And an RLC low pass filter is a second order filter for sure.

So what is the difference between to RC in series and one RLC filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *What is the advantage of RLC low pass filter over two RC connected in
>   series?*

With two RC low pass filters in series, the Q can never be greater than 0.5 and therefore it cannot make use of the peaking effects you get when you use an RLC low pass filter such as this one: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html).

Look at the red trace - around resonance you can achieve a peak in the response - this can be used to highly optimize filters and improve the pass band.

With a 2nd order filter made from cascading two RC filters you have limited peak control equivalent to the Q of the RLC circuit being a maximum of 0.5: -

[image]

The above was made to have a Q of 0.5 by increasing the series resistance to 200 ohms.

If you want the math: -

A single low pass CR stage has a transfer function of \$\dfrac{1}{1+ sCR}\$

For 2 stages and ignoring loading effects of the 2nd stage you'd get a TF of \$\dfrac{1}{(1+ sCR)^2}\$

If you rearranged this into standard form you'd get this: -

$$\dfrac{\frac{1}{C^2R^2}}{s^2 + s\frac{2}{CR} + \frac{1}{C^2R^2}}$$

And the standard form can be shown to have these equivalent parameters: -

- \$\frac{1}{C^2R^2} = \omega_n^2\$
- \$\frac{2}{CR} = 2\zeta\omega_n\$

If you rearranged these you'd find that \$\zeta\$ = 1 and, because \$\frac{1}{2\zeta} = Q\$, then Q = 0.5.

Comment: Yes - and here are some additional aspects: The denominator of the transfer function for two RC elements has two real zeroes. Hence, the transfer function has two REAL poles on the negative-real axis of the s-plane (a double pole if both sections are decoupled). Such a pole distribution does never allow Q-values above 0.5. Only in case of 2 conjugate-complex poles the Q-value is larger than 0.5 (Example: 0.7071 for a Butterworth response)

Comment: @LvW as an aside - a bit of trivia maybe about the two poles on the negative real axis - if \$\omega_n\$ is assumed to be unity (just for convenience) that one pole is the reciprocal numerically of the other i.e. if one is at -2, the other one is at -0.5. You probably knew this!

Comment: ...thank you for reminding me on these interesting properties. More than that, I rememer that this property allows us to find the VALUE of the quality factor even for real poles...(a formula with a sqrt...).

Comment: Here are some considerations for the pole-Q in case of two real poles (the symbol "a" stands for sigma on the real axis). The classical definition for the pole-Q: Qp=wp/2|a| with poles p1=a+jwn and p2=a-jwn and wp²=p1p2=a²+wn². This definition can be applied also for two real poles if we define (two real values) p1=a+wn and p2=a-wn. In this case the (fictitious) pole frequency is wp=sqrt(p1p2) (geometric mean out of the two poles) and the classical definition for the pole-Q gives Qp=sqrt(p1p2)/(p1+p2)<0.5. For p1=p2 we get Qp=0.5.